# How to delete a specific column from a query ColdFusion 11

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to delete a specific column from a query. I have already tried it with `queryDeleteColumn` however I get the error message:

> Variable QUERYDELETECOLUMN is undefined".

Here is a code snippet (ColdFusion 11.0.18):

```
<cfquery name="qData" datasource="datasource">
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table
</cfquery>
<cfset qData = QueryDeleteColumn(qData,"columnName")
```

Comment: The function `queryDeleteColumn` was added in ColdFusion 2018. So it wont be available in ColdFusion 11.

Comment: Is there maybe a similar function in coldfusion 11?

Comment: Replace `*` with just the columns you want to use.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to delete a column? Do you simply mean that you want to exclude a column from your results? If so, just don't query it. It's usually not a good practice to use `SELECT *` anyway. Do like Dan said and only query the columns that you actually want.

Comment: <psa> I would also add the caution that CF11 ended core support in April 2019, so no more security patches. This is a very not good thing, and, depending on the type of data your application deals with, it may become a fairly critical issue. </psa>

Comment: The reason for the SELECT *, is because the TABLE is variable. So I don't know all the columns. In my case I just know one specific column which is in every table. But I don't want this column in my query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `queryDeleteColumn` was added in ColdFusion 2018. So it wont be available in ColdFusion 11.

You can do a query of query on the initial result like the following.

```
<cfquery name="qData" datasource="datasource">
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table
</cfquery>

<cfif listFindNoCase(test.columnList, 'columnName')>
    <cfquery name="qData" dbtype="query">
        SELECT
          #listDeleteAt(test.columnList, listFindNoCase(test.columnList, 'columnName'))#
        FROM qData
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: @DropMania While this may have worked, I still don't see the need to do this. This will ultimately be a tremendous amount of overhead for an operation that is so much simpler by just querying the needed columns instead of `*`.